# Javascript simple matching is missing one value

Tags: javascript

I have an array that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "date": "2021-04-06",
        "count": 270
    },
    {
        "date": "2021-04-13",
        "count": 10
    }
]
```

and a small function whose job is to create an array of 14 items, where each item is either the count associated with that date (if the date matches the date in the loop), or to add a - for the date that is undefined

```
// take the date and map to the twoweekarray to see on which dates fall which count by combining them together
let combined = dates.map(function(item, index) {
  return {date: item, count: twoWeekArray[index]};
});

// set up arr and find the last day of these 2 weeks
let combinedDashValueArrayForTotalDay = [];

// go through 14 iterations for 2 weeks,
for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  let nextDay = moment().add(i, "days").format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  
  if(combined[i] !== undefined) {
    if (nextDay === moment(combined[i].date).format('YYYY-MM-DD') ) {
      combinedDashValueArrayForTotalDay.push(combined[i].count)
      console.log('combinedI', combined[i].count)
    }
  } else {
    combinedDashValueArrayForTotalDay.push('-')
  }
}
```

What is happening is that it's only matching the first date with a value, so i end up with an array that looks like `[270, -, -,- ,- ,- ,- ,- ,- ,- ,- ,- ,- ,- ,-]` when it should look like

```
[270, -, -, -, -, -, -, 10, -, -, -, -, -, -, -]
```

What am i missing? Why is it skipping that value? Is it a problem with my moment config? If that was the case, why would it grab the first item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well what you provided is array with two objects

```js
[
    {
        "date": "2021-04-06",
        "count": 270
    },
    {
        "date": "2021-04-13",
        "count": 10
    }
]
```

when you iterate over this array here:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
....
  if(combined[i] !== undefined) {
....
```

then it always going to be

```js
} else {
    combinedDashValueArrayForTotalDay.push('-')
}
```

for ids more than `1` because there are only id `0` and `1` that falls inside `if(combined[i] !== undefined)`. So it can't be like this `[270, -, -, -, -, -, -, 10, -, -, -, -, -, -, -]` it can be like this though `[270, 10, -, -, -, -, -, -, -, -, -, -, -, -, -]`. So you need to have some id that tracks where you are currently at `combined` array or, iterate over all `combined` for every iteration of `for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {`

The possible solution:

```js
const dates = [
  { date: 10, count: 150 },
  { date: 2, count: 100 },
  { date: 5, count: 1000000 }
]

const result = []

for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  let match = false
  for (let j = 0; j < dates.length; j++) {
    if (i === dates[j].date && !match) {
      result.push(dates[j].count)
      match = true
    }
  }
  if (!match) {
    result.push('-')
  }
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: great, explanation, thanks. Although your answer does not provide a solution technically.

Comment: here you go, hope you understand what I mean

Comment: Fixed an issue, sorry